# What level of WCAG is Chrome WCAG Auditor looking for?

Tags: google-chrome, wcag

I started using Google Chrome to determine WCAG compliance on my website yesterday but I'm at a loss to determine what level of WCAG it is checking for. Does anyone know? I'm running Chrome (Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)) in Windows 10.

I can't see any indication of the level of WCAG anywhere in the dialog that launches it or the report that it generates.

Comment: Are you trying to determine compliance to WCAG 2.0 or WCAG 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear what part we're talking about, you're using the Developer Tools (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>) and you selected the "Audits" tab?

The "Accessibility" checkbox will run [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) and Lighthouse uses a ruleset from [aXe](https://www.deque.com/axe/) (which you can install as a separate plugin for Chrome or Firefox).  If you click on any of the "learn more" links in your Lighthouse report, it'll take you to an aXe page, such as

> **Color Contrast Is Satisfactory**
>
> These are opportunities to improve the legibility of your content.
>
> 1. Background and foreground colors do not have a sufficient contrast ratio.
>    Low-contrast text is difficult or impossible for many users to read. [Learn more](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/2.2/color-contrast).

I could not find anything on the Lighthouse page or the aXe page that said what level of conformance the tool was looking for.  It's not until you select a "Learn more" link that you are told if the violation is a A or AA issue.  In the above color contrast link, it talks about AA even though there is also a [AAA conformance level for contrast](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast7.html).  Since aXe/Lighthouse doesn't mention AAA, I'm **guessing** the tool is only looking for A and AA issues, but it'd be nice to find an official source that states this.

Answer (score 0):

As @slugolicious wrote - Lighthouse is using Deque's aXe behind the scenes and as far as I can understand from their code it is running only WCAG 2.1 A and AA rules.

```
return window.axe.run(document, {
    elementRef: true,
    runOnly: {
      type: 'tag',
      values: [
        'wcag2a',
        'wcag2aa',
      ],
    },
```

And I've seen that they also disabled some aXe checks in Lighthouse (`{enabled: false}`);

```
rules: {
      'tabindex': {enabled: true},
      'accesskeys': {enabled: true},
      'table-fake-caption': {enabled: false},
      'td-has-header': {enabled: false},
      'marquee': {enabled: false},
      'area-alt': {enabled: false},
      'aria-dpub-role-fallback': {enabled: false},
      'aria-hidden-body': {enabled: false},
      'duplicate-id-active': {enabled: false},
      'duplicate-id-aria': {enabled: false},
      'html-xml-lang-mismatch': {enabled: false},
      'blink': {enabled: false},
      'server-side-image-map': {enabled: false},
      'aria-hidden-focus': {enabled: false},
      'form-field-multiple-labels': {enabled: false},
      'aria-input-field-name': {enabled: false},
      'aria-toggle-field-name': {enabled: false},
    },
```

(source: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/252232db9263750435e471da7ea2da1f97ef0d61/lighthouse-core/gather/gatherers/accessibility.js#L24-L51).

Then if I switch to aXe repo you can see the details;

https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/blob/482cd65e1073213a2fd7ae906a337c5ac15c3f11/doc/rule-descriptions.md#wcag-21-level-a--aa-rules

So - mainly WCAG 2.0 (53 rules) and some (3 rules) WCAG 2.1.
Please note - some rules cover same success criteria, so not rules count is not success criteria count...

Answer (score 0):

This question was posed and answered on the [Deque website](https://www.deque.com/blog/google-selects-deques-axe-chrome-devtools/):

> The Chrome Dev Tools accessibility audit is the same ruleset as the
> extension, so the testing level is the same – the axe ruleset
> currently tests against WCAG 2 rules (including 2.0, 2.1, A, AA, and
> AAA) and Section 508. The axe extension (and the library itself) does
> indicate which rules/regulations are being violated with each issue,
> but this information was not included as part of the UI for the Chrome
> Dev Tools auditor. If this is a concern for you, you may want to try
> using the axe Chrome extension instead of the Dev Tools auditor.